# when a multi dimensional random signal is WSS?

Tags: stochastic-processes

If $z_k$ be random variable and ${\phi }_{k}$ be orthogonal ( inner product of the them be zero) functions
What is the necessary and sufficient condition that this stochastic process be wide sense stationary:

$Y\left( t \right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}{{{z}_{k}}{{\phi }_{k}}\left( t \right)}$

Comment: You might find that you would get a better chance of getting an answer if you expand the acronym and explain your question more fully.